# Swith en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch

Tengo este código de javascript que lo que tiene que hacer es evaluar la letra y mostrar el departamento asociado.
El problema es que siempre va al default.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ejercicio 17</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Ejercicio 17 Estructuras selectivas</h3>
                <label for="text">Código</label>
                <input type="text">
                <input type="button" value="Verificar departamento" onclick="cartel()">
        <script type="text/javascript">

               function cartel(){
                var codigo;
                  switch(codigo){
                  case 'A':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Canelones");
                  break;
                  case 'B':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Maldonado");
                  break;
                  case 'C':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Rocha");
                  break;
                  case 'D':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Treinta y Tres");
                  break;
                  case 'E':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Cerro Largo");
                  break;
                  case 'F':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Rivera");
                  break;
                  case 'G':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Artigas");
                  break;
                  case 'H':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Salto");
                  break;
                  case 'I':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Paysandú");
                  break;
                  case 'J':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Río Negro");
                  break;
                  case 'K':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Soriano");
                  break;
                  case 'L':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Colonia");
                  break;
                  case 'M':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de San José");
                  break;
                  case 'N':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Flores");
                  break;
                  case 'O':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Florida");
                  break;
                  case 'P':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Lavalleja");
                  break;
                  case 'Q':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Durazno");
                  break;
                  case 'R':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Tacuarembó");
                  break;
                  case 'S':
                   alert("El código "+ codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Montevideo");
                  break;
                  default:
                         alert("Letra desconocida");
                  break;
                  }
                }
           </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que nunca asignas un valor a la variable `codigo` y por eso entra siempre al default. Lo único que te falta es tomar el valor de tu input y asignarlo a `codigo` o tomar el valor del input directamente. Otra cosa que debes de tomar en cuenta es que debes convertir el carácter a mayúscula o de otro modo obtendrás el mismo comportamiento que cuando no le asignas un valor.

```js
function cartel() {
  const codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value.toUpperCase();
  switch (codigo) {
    case "A":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Canelones"
      );
      break;
    case "B":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Maldonado"
      );
      break;
    case "C":
      alert("El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Rocha");
      break;
    case "D":
      alert(
        "El código " +
          codigo +
          " se corresponde al departamento de Treinta y Tres"
      );
      break;
    case "E":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Cerro Largo"
      );
      break;
    case "F":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Rivera"
      );
      break;
    case "G":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Artigas"
      );
      break;
    case "H":
      alert("El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Salto");
      break;
    case "I":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Paysandú"
      );
      break;
    case "J":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Río Negro"
      );
      break;
    case "K":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Soriano"
      );
      break;
    case "L":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Colonia"
      );
      break;
    case "M":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de San José"
      );
      break;
    case "N":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Flores"
      );
      break;
    case "O":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Florida"
      );
      break;
    case "P":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Lavalleja"
      );
      break;
    case "Q":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Durazno"
      );
      break;
    case "R":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Tacuarembó"
      );
      break;
    case "S":
      alert(
        "El código " + codigo + " se corresponde al departamento de Montevideo"
      );
      break;
    default:
      alert("Letra desconocida");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Ejercicio 17 Estructuras selectivas</h3>
<label for="codigo">Código</label>
<input id="codigo" type="text">
<input id="verificarCodigo" type="button" value="Verificar departamento" onclick="cartel()">
```

Un consejo que puedo darte es que siempre asignes ids a los elementos, en especial si te servirán para la lógica de tu programa. De este modo te será más fácil ubicarlos y trabajar con ellos.